# An equality in stopping time.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

In a proof,I need the following equality:

Suppose $\tau,\sigma$ are two stopping time and $A$ is a event.Then:
$$(A\cap\{\sigma\le\tau\})\cap\{\tau\le t\}=(A\cap\{\color{red}{\sigma}\le t\})\cap\{\color{red}{\sigma}\wedge t\le\color{red}{\tau}\wedge t\}\cap \{\tau\le t\}$$

I could deal with the "$\subset$",but I have  no idea for the opposite direction.

Comment: Are you sure this is written correctly? I ask for two reasons. First, the right side is redundant: $\{ \tau \leq t \}$ is included twice. Second, the left side will occur when $\tau,t$ are both "large", while the right side will require $\sigma$ to be "large" if $t$ is "large". This intuition generates saz's example.

Comment: I also don't see how "$\sigma \leq \tau \leq t$" could be written in a nicer form.

Comment: @Ian ,terribly sorry,I update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the equality holds true if we show that

$$\omega \in \{\sigma \leq \tau\} \Leftrightarrow \omega \in \{\sigma \leq t\} \cap \{\sigma \wedge t \leq \tau \wedge t\}$$

for any $\omega$ such that $\tau(\omega) \leq t$.

"$\subseteq$": First of all, $\sigma(\omega) \leq \tau(\omega) \leq t$ implies $\omega \in \{\sigma \leq t\}$. Moreover, this shows that $$ \sigma(\omega) \wedge t = \sigma(\omega) \leq \tau(\omega) = \tau(\omega) \wedge t$$, i.e. $\omega \in \{\sigma \wedge t \leq \tau \wedge t\}$.

"$\supseteq$": As $\sigma(\omega) \leq t$ and $\tau(\omega) \leq t$, we find that $$\underbrace{\sigma(\omega) \wedge t}_{\sigma(\omega)} \leq \underbrace{\tau(\omega) \wedge t}_{\tau(\omega)}.$$ Hence, $\omega \in \{\sigma \leq \tau\}$.

Comment: terribly sorry,I had a mistake in my question.

Comment: @paradox You are welcome. If the answer satisfies you, you can upvote it by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer.